# How to run a script every time a slider changes

Tags: javascript, slider

I currently have an [Owl carousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/) setup, with my intention being to display statistics of the site I'm working on in each slide; number of clients, number of projects etc. The statistics will be displayed via a counter up [jquery plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Animating-Numbers-Counting-Up-with-jQuery-Counter-Up-Plugin.html), which will count up to a set number at a set speed.

However it seems that once the page loads, the first counter on the first slide counts up as desired, but simultaneously, all of the counters in the other slides are being loaded too, so by the time the next slide comes along, all you are left with is a static number, rather than an animated counter.

I'm wondering if there is a way to trigger the counter script every time a new slide is selected.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Owl has an event you can hook in to for the "changed" event. [API Docs](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html)

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel();
// Listen to owl events:
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    $('span').counterUp({
        delay: 10, // the delay time in ms
        time: 1000 // the speed time in ms
    });
})
```